# JUnit test case failure: java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<null>

Tags: java, junit, jackson

I am using JUnit 4.12 and Jackson

```
@Test
public void testFailToGetDataAsString() {
    Receipt receipt = new Receipt(null);

    assertNull(receipt.getDataAsString());
}
```

The method I am testing is the following (this.data is just a null Map):

```
public String getDataAsString() {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this.data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally I run the test and check that "null" is not "< null >".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getDataAsString()` does not return null because `return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this.data);` does not throw an exception, instead it returns a string that says `"< null >"` and that does not equal to `null` of course. Instead of only returning null on catching an exception you should return null too if `writeValueAsString()` returns this custom null type.

Answer (score 1):

I finally changed the method code to:

```
public String getDataAsString() {
    try {
        if (this.data != null) {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this.data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I really don't know why this works and the previous one not.